# python: add number every new object

Tags: python

I want to change the name of the object each time a object is created so that there's an accumulator adding everytime an object is created.  In this example i want the first object.name to be B1 and then the second object.name to be B2 and then B3 and so on.  This is what im trying to get

```
 class Object:
    def __init__(self):
         self.name = "B" + (accumulator)
```

this is what I tried but i am not really getting anywhere

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.account_number = "B" + str(number = number + 1)
        self.balance = balance
```

I cant think of a way to avoid the issue of trying to set a variable to equal plus one of itself because itself isn't defined yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach here is a class variable that stores the next value to use, which you increment after use:

```
class BankAccount:
    _nextnum = 1
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.account_number = "B" + str(self._nextnum)
        type(self)._nextnum += 1  # Must set it on the class, or you only make a shadowing instance attribute
        self.balance = balance
```

This isn't thread safe without locking though, so if you want thread-safety, [`itertools.count` can do the same job](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) in a thread-safe (at least on CPython) manner:

```
import itertools

class BankAccount:
    _numgenerator = itertools.count(1)
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.account_number = "B" + str(next(self._numgenerator))
        self.balance = balance
```

Since `itertools.count`'s work is done at the C layer with [the GIL held](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL), it operates atomically, both returning the next number and moving the count along as a single atomic operation.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a class level variable maintain how many objects were created, and then use that to determine the name

```
 class BankAccount:
     count = 0
     def __init__(self):
         self.name = "B" + str(BankAccount.count)
         BankAccount.count += 1
```

This is not thread safe however, as mentioned by @ShadowRanger. It's likly a better idea to use `itertools.count` as they suggest.